# Git: Visualize "tags" only

Tags: git

I use tags to indicate releases (e.g. v1, v2, v2.1, v3, etc.).  Is there a visualizer out there that only shows the relationship between tags?  In other words, it collapses all the commits in between the tags to give a zoomed-out view of the releases.

Comment: Do you mean `gitk --tags`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest to what you want is probably `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration`. This says to traverse history starting at all tags, and treat any commit with a branch or tag as interesting.

To just focus on the commit graph, add `--graph` and `--oneline`, as well as `--decorate` to actually see the tags:

```
git log --tags --graph --oneline --decorate --simplify-by-decoration
```

Or in the gitk gui with:

```
gitk --tags --simplify-by-decoration
```

Comment: The keys here are `--tags` and `--simplify-by-decoration`, and you can get branches instead of tags with `--branches`.